# Outputting strings into a file from Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I would like to output strings into a file from an Isabelle/HOL theory.

The solution that I came up with involves doing file and string manipulation at the level of ML.

For example, let's suppose the following Isabele/HOL code that defines the abstract syntax of a very simple expression language:

```
datatype Exp = expid string
   | exppar Exp
   | expplus Exp Exp
   | expminus Exp Exp
   | expnum int
```

I would like to output the pretty-printing of expressions of this simple language into a file. For example, an expression such as:

```
definition exp_exmp :: "Exp"
where
   "exp_exmp ≡ expplus 
      (exppar (expminus (expnum 2) (expid ''x''))) 
      (exppar (expplus (expid ''y'') (expnum 5)))"
```

I managed to do this at the ML level by using the code generation features of Isabele/HOL:

```
export_code exp_exmp expid str_int in SML module_name Example file "example.sml"
```

To facilitate things with string manipulation, I have defined the pretty print function in ML. So I end up with the code:

```
ML_file "example.sml"

ML {*   
   open Example;
   fun charsToStr [] = ""
      | charsToStr (c::cs) = (str c)^charsToStr cs
   fun wrExp (Expid i) = charsToStr i
      | wrExp (Exppar e) = "(" ^ wrExp e ^ ")"
      | wrExp (Expnum n) = charsToStr (str_int n)
      | wrExp (Expplus (e1, e2)) =
         wrExp e1 ^"+"^wrExp e2
      | wrExp (Expminus (e1, e2)) =
         wrExp e1 ^ "-" ^ wrExp e2
   val file = TextIO.openOut("exmp.txt");
   TextIO.output (file, wrExp exp_exmp);
   TextIO.closeOut(file);
*}
```

In doing this, importing the theory `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Char"` was crucial to ease the necessary conversions between the Isabelle/HOL representations of chars and string and those of ML.

Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: How do you arrive at the strings? Dynamic computation? Could you please give an example of what you want to achieve?